# declare row before for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to python and would like to know if I can declare row before for loop so that I do not have to have if elif else block with for loop again.  Below is my code snippet... it loops through all files in a folder/sub-folder and inserts data in appropriate table.  My files do not have header row in files (hence defining columns in if else block).

This obviously do not work as it gives error as

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment

Would really appreciate if you can help me with some solution.

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        if len(root.split('\\')) > 4 and len(name.split('.')) > 1 and name.split('.')[1] == 'gz':
            print(dir, dirs, name, os.path.join(root, name), len(root.split('\\')))
            os.system("7z x "+ os.path.join(root, name) +" -so > " + tempFile)
            df = ps.read_csv(tempFile, sep="|")

            # No switch/match case for python v3.8
            if (root.split('\\')[4]) == 'DataSet1':
                df.columns = ['Date', 'Symbol', 'Instrument', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
                sql = "INSERT INTO data1 (timestamp, symbol, instrument_type, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price) " \
                            "VALUES (%s,       %s,          %s,          %s,          %s,         %s,         %s)"
                val = (row.Date, row.Symbol, row.Instrument, row.Open, row.High, row.Low, row.Close)
            elif (root.split('\\')[4]) == 'DataSet2':
                df.columns = ['Symbol', 'Instrument', 'CorporateAction', 'TokenNumber', 'StartDate', 'MaturityDate', 'ExerciseStartDate', 'ExerciseEndDate']
                sql = "INSERT INTO data2 (symbol, instrument_type, corporate_action, token, start_dt, maturity_dt, exer_st_dt, exer_end_dt) " \
                            "VALUES (%s,       %s,          %s,              %s,        %s,        %s,         %s,         %s)"
                val = (row.Symbol, row.Instrument, row.CorporateAction, row.TokenNumber, row.StartDate, row.MaturityDate, row.ExerciseStartDate, row.ExerciseEndDate)
            elif (root.split('\\')[4]) == 'DataSet3':
                df.columns = ['OrderNumber', 'Symbol', 'Instrument', 'CorporateAction', 'Quantity', 'LimitPrice', 'TimeStamp']
                sql = "INSERT INTO data3 (order_num, symbol, instrument_type, corporate_action, quantity, limit, timestamp) " \
                            "VALUES (%s,       %s,          %s,           %s,           %s,          %s,      %s)"
                val = (row.OrderNumber, row.Symbol, row.Instrument, row.CorporateAction, row.Quantity, row.LimitPrice, row.TimeStamp)
            else:
                continue

            for i, row in df.iterrows():
                try:
                    cursor.execute(sql, val)
                except my.Error as e:
                    if "Duplicate entry" in e.msg:
                        print(e.msg)
                    else:
                        raise
                if i % 1000 == 0:
                    mydb.commit()
            mydb.commit()
            # print (df)
        r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
return r
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might be of help - [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3.10/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you wrote your lines of code like:

```
val = (row.Date, row.Symbol, row.Instrument, row.Open, row.High, row.Low, row.Close)
```

You weren't hoping for them to act immediately on a current `row` value. Instead, you wanted this to be done later, in your `for` loop, for each row.

When you have a piece of code you want to be run multiple times, later, with different data as input, that means you want a *function*. The nice thing with functions, and the code you're trying to write, is that functions are first-class values in Python. This means that functions act like simple values and can be assigned to different variables, just like numbers or strings can. So your idea for your code, where you want to choose which way to process the data sets' rows first, and then perform it later for each row, can work easily in Python.

Since this is a one-line function returning a value, it's the perfect use case for a Python `lambda` function:

```
# inside your if statement, where you know which data set it is
# define the lamda taking the future row as its parameter
row_vals = lambda row: (row.Date, row.Symbol, row.Instrument, row.Open, row.High, row.Low, row.Close)
# ...
# inside the for loop, now we have the row
cursor.execute(sql, row_vals(row))
```

(You could also have defined functions in the ordinary way with `def`.)

---

For your actual code, a simpler way to solve this is to notice that you're using the same names in `df.columns =` and your values you're getting from your row. And the same order. And apparently you're using all of them each time. What that means is that you're naming them based on their order: `name1, name2, name3`, then getting them out in order based on their name: `1, 2, 3`. So the end result is the same as what you started with.

So you could just not name them at all:

```
cursor.execute(sql, row)
```

And it's likely you don't even need pandas, and could use the standard python csv module instead.